# How do I paginate a list of categories?

Tags: pagination

I recently added thumbnails for my categories, which has had the side effect of making the page they are listed on unbearably long. Because of that, I am hoping to paginate the list of categories.

Here is what I am using to generate the list of categories and thumbnails (unstyled):

```
<?php
 $args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
  );
$categories=get_categories('child_of=504&order_by=name&style=none&title_li=');
  foreach($categories as $category) { 
  echo '
  <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '> '. get_the_term_thumbnail ( $category->term_id, category, $size = 'medium', $attr = '') . ' </a>
  <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';
  } 
?>
```

In trying to find a solution, I came across another question ( [How to paginate a list of tags](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22093/how-to-paginate-a-list-of-tags) ) regarding tags that seems to do exactly what I am hoping, but have been unsuccessful merging the two together so far.

Any help would be wonderful,
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Untested, but this should at least be on the right track:

```
$posts_per_page = 50;

$page = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$offset = ( $page - 1 );

$args = array(
    'child_of' => 504,
    'order_by' => 'name',
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );

for( $i = $offset * $posts_per_page; $i < ( $offset + 1 ) * $posts_per_page; $i++ ) {
    $category = $categories[$i];
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '> '. get_the_term_thumbnail ( $category->term_id, category, $size = 'medium', $attr = '') . ' </a><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';
}
unset( $category );
```

## secondary pagination method

```
if( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/page/' ) !== false ) {
    $uri = explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
    foreach ( $uri as $k => $v ) {
        if ( $value == "" )
            unset( $uri[$k] );
    }
    $offset = ( array_pop($uri) * $posts_per_page ) - $posts_per_page;
}
```

That will check the URL for `/page/`, if it contains `/page/` it will strip all the empty values out and set the offset to the final value of the array. It's not the most elegant solution, but it works and its good on processing power

Comment: Thanks! When I drop that code into the site, it works perfectly for limiting the categories shown to 50.

However, when I combine it with the pagination code from the link provided above, I am getting division by zero errors after each category.

Comment: Try setting `get_query_var( 'page' )` instead of `paged` (both places) I think that should do it. The pagination is already built in, so don't try to combine them, just use this. There's no division in my code, so it' something your doing, not something I wrote that's throwing the error.

Comment: It displays 50 categories just fine, but I am not seeing any way to go to the next 50. Should I need additional code for that?

Comment: Try typing the link in directly {your current url}/page/2, the functions you should be looking at are things like `wp_link_pages()` and `posts_nav_link()`, it sorta depends on how your WP install is setup as to which will work.

Comment: {your current url} and {your current url}/page/2 return the same list of categories

Comment: What sort of diagnostics have you done? Are you sure the page number is getting pulled? Start `print_r()`ing everything until you find the issue.

Comment: Well I found one error in the code, try it now.

Comment: I'm fairly new to the technical side of wordpress, but with that instruction I was able to see that print_r($page) returns a value of 1 regardless of the page entered here: {your current url}/page/X - EDIT: am testing what you changed now

Comment: Try using the global `$page` or something like that, alternately, do the pagination by parsing the URL directly, rather than asking wordpress to parse it for you...the solution works, you just need to make it work in your case, try to do as much as you can on your own so that this thread does not get flagged for too much conversation. I'll drop a 2nd pagination method in shortly.

Comment: I was actually able to get it working by switching `get_query_var( 'page')` back to `get_query_var( 'paged')` in both areas.

No clue why it worked all of a sudden. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot move this conversation to chat yet, and I cannot seem to get an next/previous functions to recognize the need to go to the next page of categories rather than posts. Is there another way to continue in conversation?

Comment: Use the offset to generate the link. Previous page = {url}/page/$offset; next page = {url}/page/($offset+2). Filter for offset = 1 (on first page) and for count($categories)/$offset < 50 (on last page) and don't show the links at that point. If you need help on that, you can probably just start a new question.

Comment: I was able to get it working after a lot of trials using the following:

`if ($page < 2) {
    echo '<a href="{url}/page/' . ($offset+2) . '">Next</a>';
} elseif (count($categories)/$page < 48 ) {
    echo '<a href="{url}/page/' . ($offset) . '">Previous</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="{url}/page/' . ($offset) . '">Previous</a> | <a href="{url}/page/' . ($offset+2) . '">Next</a>';
}`

I really learned a lot with your help. Thank you.