# Show only the grandchildren (using get_terms)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm working with a hierarchical taxonomy (named "world") that has 3 levels to it (`Regions > Countries > Indigenous Peoples`). At the moment I'm using [a modified version of this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22101/18008) to paginate all the results on a single page.

Here's the important part

```
$page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
// number of tags to show per-page
$per_page = 24;
$offset = ( $page-1 ) * $per_page;
$args = array( 'number' => $per_page, 'offset' => $offset, 'hide_empty' => 1,'hierarchical ' => true
);
```

and

```
$taxonomy = 'world';
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
```

As expected, this returns a paginated list of all the terms associated with my taxonomy. The problem is,  I only actually need to show the grandchildren, in this case, `"Indigenous Peoples"`.

I'm tempted do it manually, but I'd rather not serve up a list of 450+ terms to include (or 80 terms to exclude) unless it's absolutely necessary.

Your help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think for each term you should check that it has a parent but not have any childern

So you code may look like

```
    $taxonomy = 'world';
    $tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
    foreach ($tax_terms as $value){
        $args=array(
            'child_of'=> $value->term_id,
            );
        //get all child of current term
        $child = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
        if( $value->parent != '0' && count($child) =='0'){
            echo $value->slug;
            echo '<br/>';
            //do something because it's your lowest level term which have parent but not have any childern
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't  you use "`parent`" parameter of [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

```
$page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
// number of tags to show per-page
$per_page = 24;
$offset = ( $page-1 ) * $per_page;
$args = array( 'number' => $per_page, 'offset' => $offset, 'hide_empty' => 1,'hierarchical ' => true,
  'parent'=>'term_id of Indigenous Peoples or whatever parent's child you want.'
);

$taxonomy = 'world';
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
```