# How to add pagination in Terms

Tags: loop, shortcode, terms, paginate-links

Hello on my website I have created a page where it will show all of the Woo Commerce tags in the store in list format. The problem here is that I am unable to paginate them. I have tried paginate_links function too but that's not working. Here is my shortcode which I created

```
function showalltags(){
    $terms = get_terms(
    array( 
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
    ) 
        );
$html = '<ul class="post_tags">';
if($terms){
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_tag' );
        $html .= "<li><a href='" . $term_link . "' title='" . $term->name . " Tag' class='" . $term->slug . "'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>";
    }
}
$html .= "</ul>";
echo $html;
}
add_shortcode('product_alltags','showalltags');
```

Comment: you should never `echo` your shortcode output, you must return it. The shortcode in your question is broken, it will cause problems with REST APIs, the shortcode will appear in the wrong order and will be broken when nested inside another shortcode, and lots of other issues. Luckily it's trivial to fix, swap `echo $html` with `return $html`

Comment: Tom is right, you should use return instead of echo something in shortcode, but your shortcode will return unordered list with terms without pagination anyway. Take a look at this question, which is similar and has an answer for you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22093/how-to-paginate-a-list-of-tags

Comment: `get_terms()` doesn't support pagination. However, you can achieve this with `number` and `offset` parameter. Also, you will need to count the max number of pages which is easily calculable by counting total and dividing by `number` parameter. Pass those data using get variable to the links.